# Reduce height of number picker

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using number picker in my activity.I want to reduce overall height of number picker.
code is

```
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/minTemp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/maxTemp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
```

its look like this
[image]
Then how to override height of number picker ??

Comment: Consider another approach. If you make the picker smaller, the buttons can become untappable.